# Java: No method to get the index of an Enum constant?

Tags: java, enums, integer

I really wonder if there is an efficient way to get the index of an Enum constant.
I could think of two methods:
iterationg over the MyEnum.values()
or giving every constant an integer that identifies it like so:

```
public enum MyEnum {

    CONSTANT_ONE(0),
    CONSTANT_TWO(1),
    CONSTANT_THREE(2),
    CONSTANT_FOUR(3);

    private int index;

    private MyEnum(int index){
        this.index = index;
    }

    public int getIndex(){
        return index;
    }

}
```

But both of these methods seem a bit... circuitous to me.
Is there a better, or even a official way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean getting position of enum constant without having to use extra variable, you can use [`Enum#ordinal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) method.